# Javascript loading FBX 6100 and FBX SDK 2011 (3D file)

Tags: javascript, 3d, fbx

Are there any way or lib to load FBX 6100 and FBX SDK 2011 (3D file) with Textures?
I've known three.js just support FBX 7100 above.